# VBS: how to parse "if"

Tags: vbscript

I want to parse code: how to see, that End If ends not last IF, but first IF? How vbs does it?

```
If FSO.FolderExists(F) Then
  Test = 1 : Filt = 160 : BN = FSO.GetFileName(F)
Else
  Test = 0 : Filt = 192 : BN = FSO.GetBaseName(F)
  If C = 3 Then Ext = "." & FSO.GetExtensionName(F)
End If : Ent = InStrRev(BN, "(") : Max = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one `If()` statement, and one other `If()` statement that is placed inside.  The second `If()` statement uses special syntax for one line only.

The colons `:` are just a way to make two lines go onto one line.  So removing those:

```
If FSO.FolderExists(F) Then
  Test = 1 
  Filt = 160 
  BN = FSO.GetFileName(F)
Else
  Test = 0 
  Filt = 192 
  BN = FSO.GetBaseName(F)

  If C = 3 Then Ext = "." & FSO.GetExtensionName(F)

End If 

Ent = InStrRev(BN, "(")
Max = 0
```

If this is not enough to make the logic clear, then you should learn the basics of the `If()` statement.

Comment: If I see "then" and a text, it's one line syntax of "if"?

Comment: Correct.  It's a shorthand version that does not close with `End If`.